# Running exe with parameters in bash and passing it's output to another program

Tags: bash

I have to call one prog1.exe program and give arguments to it and give it's output to another executable prog2.exe in a bash script

```
prog1 "arguments" | prog2
echo finished
```

How can I make this to work? Also I suppose `echo` command won't be executed before prog2 will finish it's work?

**EDIT :**
When I run

```
prog1 "argument"
prog2 "example"
prog1 "argument" | prog2
```

I got correct output from prog1 -  `std::cout << "arguments" << std::endl` and it's displayed nicely in console and also prog2 is creating file `example.txt` so individually both programs are working. Just puting them together with `prog1 "arguments" | prog2` doesn't do the trick

Comment: You wrote it correctly. Have you tried it, does it not work?

Comment: The `echo` will only run after both `prog1` and `prog2` have exited.

Comment: Yes it's not working. I made prog2 to create text file with name that prog1 gave it but it acts as no parameters are given

Comment: @etrusks pipes do not add parameters, they send to stdin of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't a bash question.  This is a C++ question really.  prog2 should be reading from stdin as jordanm suggested in the comments.  Something like this will read from stdin line by line:

```cpp
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Change the `cout` to do whatever you want with it on each line.